# Will restricting a folder with .htaccess hinder internal server cron job access to a php file within that folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, scripting, cron

I have a GoDaddy server upon which I have a Cron job setup running a php script once per day.  I would like to restrict public access to this script.  Will restricting the folder in which the script is located via .htaccess hinder my server's internal ability to run the script with the cron job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess` are handled by webserver (eg apache). Cron jobs are scheduled tasks which is independent of your htaccess. So non it will not hinder.

Just you need to make sure your script permissions are OK.